# 2013 page with code embed directs to /_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/orgininalName?

Tags: markup, sitepages

Not sure why, but a page with some markup code embeded into it results in the a url that looks like this.

/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/orgininalName ?

and for whatever reason does not bind and render some knockout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of `/_layouts/15/start.aspx` in the URL by going to Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Manager Site Features -> Deactivate Minimal Download Strategy feature

However this is a new framework in SharePoint 2013, which increases performance of SharePoint site..

More reading here:

[What is /_layouts/15/start.aspx](http://www.hezser.de/blog/archive/2012/08/18/what-is-the-_layouts15start-aspx-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

[Why does /_layouts/15/start.aspx appear as part of SharePoint 2013 URL](http://www.drisky.co.uk/2013/05/30/why-does-_layouts15start-aspx-appear-as-part-of-my-sharepoint-2013-url/)

Comment: this fixed my issue, but other stuff was going on too, not only url changing, but page was not binding and now it is.. i'm not sure why it fixed it and why that page tho.